# Problem with adding button to navigation bar.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I added button on navigation bar.

When am navigating from rootviewcontroller to detailedviewcontroller

and getting back from detailedviewcontroller to rootviewcontroller.

those button which are on navigation bar removed and added to view.  That is back to navigation bar

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show me where and how you add the buttons, so we can grt a clue of whats going on...

Comment: Please Clarify your Q by bringing pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the buttons on **viewDidLoad**, allocate them during the **viewDidLoad** and add them on **viewDidAppear**. This should help putting them up every time the view appears (for any reason).